# Change the Safari home page for the OSX Guest account

Tags: macos, safari, guest-account

I'd like to setup the guest account with easy access to a particular web site, but cannot figure out how to change the default.

In 10.5.8 the parental controls can be used to control the list of bookmarks, but I haven't seen any reference to the home page.  And when logged in as Guest, the home page settings are read-only, even if you enter an administrator password.

How can the Safari home page be changed (and be made persistent) for the OSX Guest account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a default user template on your computer that is called upon when you create a new account, be it administrator, standard or guest. You can modify that template to make this (or other changes) to the account. Here is a walkthrough of the process I found.

http://web.archive.org/web/20111211133001/http://www.michaelsmac.com/modules.php?name=News&file=article&sid=394

Just be aware that you are modifying the template that all accounts use, and of course Apple may overwrite your changes in a future update.

Also, it is well worth mentioning that there is a serious bug that can cause data loss in your regular admin account if you log into a guest account in 10.6 or 10.6.1. Fortunately the 10.6.2 update just came out today, so be sure to grab that.

Comment: Thanks, that's all good to know.  And the reason the home page locked was because Parental controls were enabled for the Guest account.  So Parental controls shouldn't be enabled when following the walkthrough.

Answer (score 0):

ik heb een gastaccount aangemaakt en op het bureaublad zie ik een vraagteken boven safari staan, verplaatst ik dit vraagteken dan verdwijnt het plotseling. Je kan dus als je ingelogd bent op de gastaccount geen internet verbinding krijgen omdat je geen safari hebt. Hoe krijg ik het icoon weer terug op mijn bureaublad bij mijn aangemaakte gastaccount zodat je daar ook op op internet kan.

bedankt voor de hulp.

Comment: Hi Bas, please read the FAQ and understand this is not a forum (and it's not Dutch). I think your question is not related to this existing question, so I guess you can ask your own question, if you cannot find your answer here elsewhere.

Comment: (As an aside: the OS X guest account is a built-in auto-cleaning account which can be enabled, but does not need to be "created". See http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.5/en/15600.html)